# How would I solve this SQL exercise?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

Hypothetically, I have a table, `EMPLOYEES`, that has a `SALARY` column which consists of:

```
30250
35260
7340
60185
```

Also, hypothetically, we have a person that calculates these salaries on a calculator with a broken '0' key. So the entries are:

```
325
3526
734
6185
```

Now I am tasked with finding the difference of the actual average and the "broken key" average to see how much this person was off by. How would I go about getting the "broken key" average?

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Comment: I feel like I've read this already.  Did your last question with Little Debbie get closed and you asked it again?

Comment: I deleted it and asked the question again in a way that eliminated all ambiguity. This isn't a school assignment. I'm practicing SQL on a website and I'm trying to figure out how to go about solving this problem. I appreciate the assumption though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to remove the zeros, and then just subtract the two averages:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) - AVG(REPLACE(salary, '0', '')) AS mistake
FROM   employees
```

Comment: Didn't know about the replace function. Thanks a lot! I figured there was an easier way than having to cast from int to char, remove 0's then cast it back.

Comment: @juice Yeah, I know, I'm not a fan of these implicit casts either, but I couldn't thinks of a "mathematical" way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @MichaelMcGriff!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find which row is on error condition?
You could use a "left join" sentence, finding wich data from the first table is not on the another table